# How to find unmapped control keys in vim?

Tags: vim

I would like to do something like

`map <C-k> :e#<CR>`

in my `.vimrc`.

However, I recently found that `<C-k>` is used for digraphs.

**How do I get a list of unmapped control keys in vim?**

Comment: I am not sure there are any. I generally map to `<leader>...` sequences and function keys for my own extensions.

Comment: +1 @Amadan - lol for an unexpected answer - I do use <leader> for some sequences (eg NERDtree), but the `:#e<CR>` is so common I thought I'd bind it to a direct control key.  Guess I need to find one that I don't use...

Comment: I use `<F2>` for NERDTree. Nice, and free. Put common things on function keys, since they're not taken.

Comment: … and that's exactly what they are made for.

Comment: `<C-k>` is not used for digraphs in any mode for which `:map` command defines a mapping, it is used for digraphs in insert and command mode. In fact, it is used for nothing in any other mode, including all modes handled by `:map`. You need `:nnoremap` here though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim has many commands, so it can be a challenge to find a (memorable and short) key sequence for mappings.

My approach is to use the recommended `<Leader>` prefix for things I do not use frequently, but for essential stuff a mapping with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is useful, indeed.

Learn how the commands are represented in the help (e.g. `CTRL-O` in normal mode, `i_CTRL-X_CTRL-N` for insert mode), think of a good mapping candidate, then try to look it up via `:help CTRL-...`) If there are no matches, you can make sure that the mapping is free via `:nmap C-...`; if there is a match (the nice thing is that this also covers plugins that supply documentation), you can read the description, have at least discovered a new Vim command, and can then decide whether you need it (then retry with a different mapping candidate), or whether you override the command.

(Note that you can also `:noremap` built-in commands to other keys, but be aware that this makes you increasingly helpless in vanilla Vim installations or other application's vi-emulation modes.)

Answer (score 2):

I just akc'd the documentation directory for vim 7.4 debian/ubuntu package to find used control keys.

the command I used was

```
ack ctrl- | perl -ne 'm/(CTRL-.?)/g; print $1."\n";' | sort| uniq
```

The output is below

```
CTRL-^
CTRL-<
CTRL-_
CTRL--
CTRL-;
CTRL-?
CTRL-(
CTRL-[
CTRL-]
CTRL-{
CTRL-@
CTRL-\
CTRL-6
CTRL-a
CTRL-A
CTRL-B
CTRL-C
CTRL-D
CTRL-E
CTRL-F
CTRL-G
CTRL-H
CTRL-I
CTRL-J
CTRL-K
CTRL-L
CTRL-M
CTRL-N
CTRL-O
CTRL-P
CTRL-Q
CTRL-R
CTRL-s
CTRL-S
CTRL-T
CTRL-U
CTRL-V
CTRL-W
CTRL-x
CTRL-X
CTRL-Y
CTRL-Z
```

Basically no free ctrl keys . . .  Yay! :)

Answer (score 1):

There's already a `<C-…` shortcut for that: `<C-^>` (or `<C-6>` in some cases).